# PHP_PDO float to string conversion different than SQLSRV itself

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

After googling around I discovered that PDO_SQLSRV returns string values, as per the php spec for PDO

However, **why does the PDO return different values than sql when a sql query has cast a value to a varchar?**

PHP:

```
myDbWrapperFunction("SELECT CAST(CAST(0.03 as varchar(250))as FLOAT)"); // 2.9999999999999999E-2
myDbWrapperFunction("SELECT 0.03"); // .03
myDbWrapperFunction("SELECT CAST(0.03 as varchar(250))"); // 0.03
```

in SQL itself however:

```
select cast(cast(0.03 as varchar(250))as float) //0.03
select cast(0.03 as varchar(250)) //0.03
select 0.03 //0.03
```

I would expect

```
myDbWrapperFunction("SELECT CAST(CAST(0.03 as varchar(250))as FLOAT)"); // 2.9999999999999999E-2
```

to return the same value as

```
select cast(0.03 as varchar(250)) //0.03
```

Is sql cheating with float values?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Comment: That shouldn't be relevant, as SQL / PHP should have the same behavior when converting (string) -> (float). They don't, ergo my question.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, you need to cast using STR instead of CASTing to VARCHAR:

SELECT STR(MyField,10,2)

Source: http://jwcooney.com/2013/09/25/sql-server-rounds-floats-when-casting-to-varchar/